# What's the translation for Mammalian Two-Hybrid System to Chinese?

Tags: translation

is there anyone who can help me translate [Mammalian Two-Hybrid System](http://www.creativebiomart.net/Mammalian-Two-Hybrid-System.htm) into Chinese? I'm not sure is it 哺乳动物双杂交系统? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Seems fine to me, but I'm not sure whether it's a correct technical term for the special domain.

Comment: Wikipedia and iciba: ( 酵母菌)双杂合系统 (Yeast) two hybrid system (合 instead of 交)

Comment: `哺乳动物细胞双杂交系统`, I don't know why they emphasize "细胞(cell)" in the translation as I'm not an expert on this subject, but it's a [jargon that Chinese experts would actually use in their papers](http://dict.cnki.net/dict_result.aspx?searchword=Mammalian%20Two-Hybrid%20System). For translation of such terminologies, you can try [dict.cnki.net](http://dict.cnki.net) – it will list translations by citing corresponding papers so you can verify if the context is OK.

Comment: @Stan [Hybridization is the result of mixing two species's genes][1]. In scientific terms, hybridization is done in cell level.
So there is "细胞(cell)" in the phrase.
However, [Yeast are eukaryotic microorganisms][1]. To put it simply, they are cells. I think in order to avoid repeating it, the phrase "Yeast two hybrid system" is not contain "细胞(cell)".

  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_(biology)#Interspecific_hybrids
  [2]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeast

Comment: @zz22 thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 2):

According after reading your reference :

> Mammalian Two-Hybrid System

Original record is talking about "protein-protein interactions in mammalian cells". The protein is not living thing so it can't 雜交, 交合, 雜交 (these terms mean cross mating).

It seems below is better.

```
哺乳動物細胞雙混合系統
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a related on, [yeast two hybrid system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-hybrid_screening), which is 酵母菌双杂合系统. So your answer should be 哺乳动物双杂合系统 in simplified Chinese.